# Performing buffering and intersection with script in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, buffer, intersection

I wrote a script that performs the intersection of two layers:

- The first Layer -> `layer1`, represents the rivers
- The second Layer -> `layer2`, represents a set of circular dots distributed in a geographical area (at each point corresponds to a numeric value that exceeds a threshold value)

The result of the intersection should be highlighted with an operation of buffering.

The new geometry obtained with Intersection + Buffering should produce a layer that surrounds the traits of the rivers and the point or more points that intersect.

[image]

Writing from console PyQGIS I have not encountered any errors. To see the new geometry I added new layers to the previous ones (from "add vector layer") but I have not seen anything new.

This is the code of my script:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()

layers = canvas.layers()
layer1 = canvas.layer(0)
layer2 = canvas.layer(3)

from qgis.analysis import *

overlayAnalyzer = QgsOverlayAnalyzer()
overlayAnalyzer.intersection(layer1, layer2, "/home/..../Scrivania/..../output.shp")

layer3 = canvas.layer(0)

geometryanalyzer = QgsGeometryAnalyzer()
geometryanalyzer.buffer(layer3, "/home/..../Scrivania/..../buffer.shp", 500, False, False, -1)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you please edit your question to include your image if it was meant to be included? When adding an image, you should see a reference at the very bottom of your post like **"[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/...**". Keep this in.

Comment: I am sorry to point this out, but I am missing your question. What's the point of this post? Could you kindly state your question directly, in the very beginning of this post, and they follow it up with the already given description?

Comment: Is there an actual question? Or just a method of doing something. This could be better phrased as a question, then providing the script as an answer.